How do I edit the modal data-bs-keyboard attribute with javascript in bootstrap v5?
I am trying to have a sort of settings panel that enables/disables the data-bs-keyboard property of my modals, allowing or disallowing them to close with the escape key.
So far the only code that worked is this:
 // assume the 'modal' variable contains my modal
 let bootstrapInstance = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(modal);
 bootstrapInstance._config.keyboard = false;

The problem is this only works after the modals have already been initialised. If the setting is triggered as soon as the site launches, there are no modal instances yet and the code doesn't work.
I've tried below but it also does not work:
$('#myModal').data('bs.modal')._config.keyboard = false; // or true


Here is how I got it to work:
use the "getOrCreateInstance()" function instead of the getInstance() function. This will create a new instance of the modal should one not already be there. As a result the rest of the code will always work.
 let bootstrapInstance = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(modal);
 bootstrapInstance._config.keyboard = false; // or true

I tried various other methods, but most will not work if some of your modals have already been initialised. If none of your modals have been initialised when the setting is toggled, then you can also change default Modal settings:
 bootstrap.Modal.Default.keyboard = true; // or false

Or you can select a specific modal and change its data-bs-keyboard attribute, which you will find is located as below:
$('#myModal')[0].attributes[3].value = true; // or false

you can 'console.log($('#myModal'));' to understand this path.
Again, the last two will not work on already initialised modals. you can always call the getInstance() function to check if a modal instance exists when you're trying to change settings.
I doubt there is a cleaner way than the first one so I'm posting this as the solution.
